# I'm getting this error while sshing to remote box. How do I fix this

Tags: ssh

I'm not able to ssh to remote host. This was happening before but I'm not able to figure out what has changed in the past couple of days.

I tried debugging and this is the debug output

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.33.165.74 [10.33.165.74] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 10.33.165.74:22 as 'aditya.natarajan'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:fdH3ixGu9jgX2/X8P70JcOgxs1OcfX/7IgOvkKhpTQE
Warning: Permanently added '10.33.165.74' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

But my keys are present in .ssh and permissions seem alright. Or am I missing something?

```
ls -alF .ssh/
    total 168
    drwx------   8 aditya.natarajan  FKIPL\Domain Users    272 Oct  7 17:36 ./
    drwxr-xr-x+ 81 aditya.natarajan  FKIPL\Domain Users   2754 Oct  7 17:41 ../
    -rw-------   1 aditya.natarajan  FKIPL\Domain Users   3327 Mar  1  2016 co-user
    -rw-------   1 aditya.natarajan  FKIPL\Domain Users    734 Mar  1  2016 co-user.pub
    -rw-------   1 aditya.natarajan  FKIPL\Domain Users     75 Sep 29 19:42 config
    -rw-------   1 aditya.natarajan  FKIPL\Domain Users   1766 Jul  8  2015 id_rsa
    -rw-------   1 aditya.natarajan  FKIPL\Domain Users    417 Jul  8  2015 id_rsa.pub
    -rw-------   1 aditya.natarajan  FKIPL\Domain Users  64233 Sep 29 17:55 known_hosts
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [su] or [unix.se].

Comment: Oh didn't know that. I'll post it there.